# How to hide navigation bar and only show specific tags?

Tags: html, typescript, next.js, tailwind-css, radix-ui

I have created an aesthetically pleasing navigation bar, drawing inspiration from the home page of https://www.vercel.com. I utilized shadnc-ui AKA radix-ui components, tailwindcss, and next.js for this development. However, I am currently questioning the possibility of achieving a sleek and minimalist design. Specifically, I am interested in hiding the navigation bar and displaying only the `<Image>` tag and a `<HamburgerMenuIcon>` (lucide-react) when it is 800 pixels or less, and leaving the rest untouched.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Link from 'next/link';
import Image from 'next/image';
import {
  NavigationMenu, NavigationMenuContent, NavigationMenuItem,
  NavigationMenuLink,
  NavigationMenuList,
  NavigationMenuTrigger,
  navigationMenuTriggerStyle,
} from "@/components/ui/navigation-menu";
import {
  Command, CommandDialog, CommandEmpty,
  CommandGroup, CommandInput, CommandItem,
  CommandList, CommandSeparator, CommandShortcut,
} from "@/components/ui/command";
import { cn } from '@/lib/utils';
import { buttonVariants } from '@/components/ui/button';
import { Icons } from "@/components/ui/icons";

export function NavigationBar() {
  // State for controlling the visibility of a command dialog
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  // Function to handle the click event on a link and open the command dialog
  const handleLinkClick = () => setOpen(true);

  // Render the component with JSX
  return (
    <>
      <CommandDialog open={open} onOpenChange={setOpen}>
        <CommandInput placeholder="Type and search for product..." />
        <CommandList>
          <CommandEmpty>No results found.</CommandEmpty>
        </CommandList>
      </CommandDialog>
      <nav className='flex items-center justify-between p-4'>
        <Image src='/vercel.svg'  width={125} height={50} alt=''></Image>
        <NavigationMenu>
          <NavigationMenuList>
            <NavigationMenuItem>
              <NavigationMenuTrigger>Home</NavigationMenuTrigger>
              <NavigationMenuContent>
                <ul className="grid gap-3 p-4 md:w-[400px] lg:w-[500px] lg:grid-cols-[.75fr_1fr]">
                  <li className="row-span-3">
                    <NavigationMenuLink asChild>
                      <Link
                        className="flex h-full w-full select-none flex-col justify-end rounded-md bg-gradient-to-b from-muted/50 to-muted p-6 no-underline outline-none focus:shadow-md"
                        href="/"
                      >
                        <Icons.logo className="h-6 w-6"></Icons.logo>
                        <div className="mb-2 mt-4 text-lg font-medium">
                          Nunc Quam Varius
                        </div>
                        <p className="text-sm leading-tight text-muted-foreground">
                          Nunc quam varius, eu tincidunt odio condimentum. Pellentesque id quam id justo hendrerit congue. Ut sed tortor a nibh fermentum vestibulum.
                        </p>
                      </Link>
                    </NavigationMenuLink>
                  </li>
                  <ListItem
                    href="/"
                    title="Lorem Ipsum Adventures: Dolor Sit Amet Consectetur"
                    description="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
                  ></ListItem>
                </ul>
              </NavigationMenuContent>
            </NavigationMenuItem>
            <NavigationMenuItem>
              <NavigationMenuTrigger>Application</NavigationMenuTrigger>
              <NavigationMenuContent>
                <ul className="grid w-[400px] gap-3 p-4 md:w-[500px] md:grid-cols-2 lg:w-[600px]">
                  <ListItem
                    href="/"
                    title="Lorem Ipsum Dreams: Viverra Mollis Ipsum"
                    description="Viverra mollis ipsum id volutpat. Fusce hendrerit nec libero quis bibendum. Nullam eget metus et justo congue fermentum."
                  ></ListItem>
                </ul>
              </NavigationMenuContent>
            </NavigationMenuItem>
            <NavigationMenuItem>
                <NavigationMenuLink onClick={handleLinkClick} className={navigationMenuTriggerStyle()}>
                  Products
                </NavigationMenuLink>
            </NavigationMenuItem>
            <NavigationMenuItem>
              <Link href="/docs" legacyBehavior passHref>
                <NavigationMenuLink className={navigationMenuTriggerStyle()}>
                  Docs
                </NavigationMenuLink>
              </Link>
            </NavigationMenuItem>
            <NavigationMenuItem>
              <Link href="/blog" legacyBehavior passHref>
                <NavigationMenuLink className={navigationMenuTriggerStyle()}>
                  Blog
                </NavigationMenuLink>
              </Link>
            </NavigationMenuItem>
          </NavigationMenuList>
        </NavigationMenu>
        <div className="flex space-x-4">
          <Link href='/auth/sign-in' className={buttonVariants({ variant: "default" })}>
            Sign In
          </Link>
          <Link href='/' className={buttonVariants({ variant: "outline" })}>
            Log In
          </Link>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </>
  );
}

const ListItem = React.forwardRef<
  React.ElementRef<typeof Link>,
  React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<typeof Link> & { title: string; description: string }
>(({
  className,
  title,
  description,
  ...props
}, ref) => {
  return (
    <li>
      <NavigationMenuLink asChild>
        <Link
          ref={ref}
          className={cn(
            "block select-none space-y-1 rounded-md p-3 leading-none no-underline outline-none transition-colors hover:bg-accent hover:text-accent-foreground focus:bg-accent focus:text-accent-foreground",
            className
          )}
          {...props}
        >
          <div className="text-sm font-medium leading-none">{title}</div>
          <p className="line-clamp-2 text-sm leading-snug text-muted-foreground">
            {description}
          </p>
        </Link>
      </NavigationMenuLink>
    </li>
  );
});
```